# Best model to use with prediction on Medical Technology waves

Tags: python, medical

I am currently Working on a program that can predict the likelihood of someone developing an illness using the lab results which will be waves (image of the wave or processed into a .csv) like heartbeats, Electromyogram, etc. I am planning on using Python and implementing it on an Arduino nano Board

but I don't know where to start with the software. what would be the best models or architectures to use?

I found some sample data on Kaggle and I'm thinking of testing it out using those data
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nccvector/electromyography-emg-dataset/code

Comment: If you have already a computer to capture and/or process the image and/or generate a csv, why aren't you using it to complete the analysis and prediction? Where will the embedded fits in the topology? And if you intend to start with it and capture the waves, this is a different question all together.

Comment: I don't have the Data yet I was planning on trying out the csv from kaggle I read from a study in https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-22877-8#Sec8 they were testing cardiac amyloidosis using electrocardiograms and echocardiograms and they used 2D-CNN for their model I was wondering if there is a better model that could fit any types of wave data or will it be different with different types of wave data.

Comment: Seems to me you are looking for answers at the wrong place.